# Luracast Restler in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, rest

I am trying to put in Restler as part of my CI Library. I wonder if this is possible with Restler because I'm getting Server Error. Should I just separate Restler folder to my CI folder (which works right now)?

I want to integrate it to my CI so I can access the models e.g for authentication, getting user data...etc. instead of creating another config file and model classes.

I have invested a lot of time trying to find some workaround to make Restler work with CI but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I will also look at the possibilities. In this case we need to leave the routing to CI and let restler handle the output. Also I'm glad that you love Restler and cloned ActiveRecord. Would you like to contribute that to the community? It will be a great addition to Restler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to integrate Restler into CI, you would have to totally rework the CI routing class.

I would recommend that you instead go with Phil Sturgeon's excellent [REST server for CI](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver), which is a pretty simple to put into your existing CI application.

Comment: Yep. I've tried for hours but I'm not all that programming God to figure a workaround. What I did instead was to clone the ci active record for my Restler API use instead, so it's Restler with CI. I've seen Phil Sturgeon's work but I still prefer Restler. :) Thank you for your input! Appreciate it.

Comment: You should also check out the [NotORM](http://www.notorm.com/) library too, it's a good drop-in database abstraction library.